# Missing interface property error but it's actually not missing

Tags: reactjs, typescript, reach-router

I'm currently in the process of switching a big project to TypeScript. I'm very new and unused to it.

So, using `@reach/router`, I have the following routing :

```
import { Router } from '@reach/router'

export default () => (
  <main id='container'>
    <div>
      <Error>
        <Router>
          <Sign path='sign/*'/>
          <Dashboard path='/'/>
        </Router>
      </Error>
    </div>
  </main>
)
```

`Sign` is the defined as follows :

```
import { Router, Link, Redirect, RouteComponentProps } from '@reach/router'

interface DefaultProps extends RouteComponentProps {
  '*': string
}

export default ({ '*': mode }: DefaultProps) => {
  return (
    <div id='sign'>
      <Router className={cn({ signup: mode === 'up' })}>
        // ...other routes
      </Router>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I get the following error :

```
Property ''*'' is missing in type '{ path: string; }' but required in type 'DefaultProps'.  TS2741

    29 |       <Error>
    30 |         <Router>
  > 31 |           <Sign path='sign/*'/>
       |            ^
```

What's the issue ?

Comment: Did you ever find a workaround for this? I just converted our routes to TS using `@reach/router`. Same TS error is popping up for me no matter how I approach it.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing `path` to `Sign` component and it should be included in your interface. Interface should include all props passed to your component so if you're not passing `*` to it, TS will throw an error.

Also, it's better to use named exports and React.FC components with TypeScript.

Here's an explanation on that topic:
https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/tips/defaultIsBad.html
https://levelup.gitconnected.com/usetypescript-a-complete-guide-to-react-hooks-and-typescript-db1858d1fb9c

Comment: `path` is defined in `RouteComponentProps`, and `*` is passed (this is managed by `@reach/router`)

Comment: @Strebler Ok, didn't know that. Have you tried installing/re-installing reach/router types with `yarn add @types/reach__router`?

Answer (score 0):

```
Property ''*'' is missing in type '{ path: string; }' but required in type 'DefaultProps'.
```

What is `{ *: mode }` for? The only supposed usage of it so far is:

```
<Sign path='sign/*'/>
```

If we were to satisfy your prop definition it should be:

```
Sign path='sign/*' *='somethingelse' />
```

In this case * is not a valid prop since it's not a valid variable name.

The only prop required by `Sign` is `path` which `RouteComponentProps` simply provides it for you.

It seems in your code as well that you're using `mode` as a variable, not `*`, and if you mean `mode` is an optional prop in the `Sign` component, then it should be written as follows:

```
interface DefaultProps extends RouteComponentProps {
  mode?: string
}

export default ({ mode }: DefaultProps) => {
  return (
    <div id='sign'>
      <Router className={cn({ signup: mode === 'up' })}>
        // ...other routes
      </Router>
    </div>
  )
}
```

It also looks like mode is a string literal which could be exhaustive, so you can also optimize by doing:

`type mode = 'up' | 'down'`

Comment: `*` is a valid property name, and props are just an object. This naming is not of my choice, it comes from `@reach/router`. The property `*` contains the actual subpath string from `sign/*`. This is correct and works perfectly in plain JS.